# Woocommerce add_action not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to replace the product thumbnail based on stock.  This works if I plop it directly into the wc-template-functions woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail function, but not when I try to hook into it from functions.php.  This is my code:

```
   function sold_out_thumb ($size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height =     0 ) {
   global $product;
   global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
        if ($product->price > 0 && !$product->is_in_stock() ) 
            return get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size,array( 'class' => 'lighter' ) );
        else 
            return get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size );

    elseif ( wc_placeholder_img_src() )
        return wc_placeholder_img( $size );
  }

   add_action ('woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail','sold_out_thumb',90);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in `wc-template-functions.php`, almost all template functions are inside `if ( !function_exists() )` condition. That way the creators of the plugin enabled us to override template functions, so just create `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()` function in functions.php, and the original will not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no action called `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail` which is why this isn't working for you. This is actually a function called [`woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail.html). If you look at the code there is [no action hook](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail.html#602-619).